# How to hide add to cart button for particular products on all page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, product-list

How to hide  add to cart  button   for particular products on all page in magento 2

To hide add to cart button all page  using a below plugin:

> di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="hidebutton" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\HideButton" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

> HideButton.php

```
 <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

    class HideButton
    {
        public function afterIsSaleable(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject,
        $result
    ) {
       if($subject->getId() == 36)
       {
         return false;
       }
       else
       {
        return  true;
       }

    }
    }
```

Above plugin works well but its shows an "Out of Stock" instead of "Add to cart" 
 in listing and home page  how to hide a "out of stock" text.

[image]

Comment: You  can add attribute  and manage yes  or no and manage it on that product page. okay

Comment: i tried that way already  as you said above. its only hide in product details and listing page but i need to hide in all page  like home page, wishlish page , compare list page  etc

Comment: you need to put that in all pages.

Comment: have you using any theme?

Comment: here is you focusing Out of stock button. and you mentioned other buttons in questions.

Comment: No i using default luma theme

Comment: are you working in localhost?

Comment: s i working in localhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104633/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-divya-sekar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use **afterIsSalable()** plugin using this below way :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="hidebutton" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>

</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Product.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Product
{               
    public function afterIsSaleable(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        if(your_condition_check)
        {
            return true; // For display button
        }else {
            return false; // For hide button
        }
    }
}
```

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: S, its work well its hide a add to cart button in all page but its show a "Out of stock" instead of "Add to cart" button, now my question is how to hide a out of stock text

Comment: You used wrong after plugin function. Please check my function name.

Comment: Thank you so much   for a intimate a bug. now its works fine.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy Coding (y)

Comment: @RohanHapani Works great. However, is it possible to return anything else ("Please login") or something like this when button is hidden?

Comment: @zlep No you just passed boolean value based on condition. After that you can set button text or etc where this function is call. Mark as upvote if it will useful for you.

Comment: @RohanHapani Thanks, could you please give an example? I quite don't get what you mean. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is can be done by Override addtocart.phtml

https://magenticians.com/magento-2-disable-add-to-cart-button/

I hope this link is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but  i don't want to  override a templates i need to done by without overriding a template

Comment: i used a plugin as you post above. but its show "Out of stock" instead of "Add to Cart" button. i need to show  only blank space  not a add to cart button or out of stock text

Comment: you can disable  it by going into Stores->Configure->From Catalog drop-down select 'Inventory'->uncheck and choose no for Display Out Of Stock Products'

Comment: its already  default set as no only refer it  https://prnt.sc/r4fkkr

Comment: Try this also . Go to admin > Stores > configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options Set Backorders to "No Backorders"

Comment: its already default set as "no  backorder" https://prnt.sc/r4fmur