# Magento2 - disable add to cart on product page

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart

Im running Magento2.3.4 and would like to `disable` the add to cart bottom on some product pages because they are to complicated to ship.

Have created an `Yes/No` attribute "afhentes" and I would like to disable the add to cart by enable this attribute.

One the same time I would like a text displayed indsteed: "`Pick up in store`"

Have found some around the net but they does not seem to work.

Hope someone can help med out with this matter.

Comment: I guess this link can help with proper steps
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304604/how-to-hide-add-to-cart-button-for-particular-products-on-all-page-in-magento-2

Comment: This hides the add to cart bottum on all pages.
I wan to be able to set on with products the add to cart must be removed by my attriute.

Comment: okay you can append is current page product page condition, using registry('current_product')

Comment: and how do I do that? :)

Comment: sample link https://mage2-blog.com/magento-2-get-current-product/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below code in your

> app/design/frontend/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->getData('afhentes') != 1): ?>
        <div class="box-tocart">
            <div class="fieldset">
                <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
                <div class="field qty">
                    <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="number"
                            name="qty"
                            id="qty"
                            value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                            title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                            class="input-text qty"
                            data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <button type="submit"
                            title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                            class="action primary tocart"
                            id="product-addtocart-button">
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
                    </button>
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <b><?= __('Pick up in store'); ?></b>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Flush the cache and check, It works for me, Check this screenshot.

[image]

Hope this work for you.

Comment: I use the Ultimo theme so that might be the issue.
addtocart.phtml is not in the app etc folder.
Ultimo uses the file from the vendor dir.

Comment: So you can copy the vendor file in the ultimo theme path which i given and update the code.

Comment: Gets this error for the variable _product
"Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: _product in /var/www/testmigreparkogf.dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml on line 9"

Comment: have you replaced whole file?

Comment: Yes I have. Will look a bit closer and see what it could be

Comment: I have updated my answer, Now replace the whole code with my updated code in your file and flush the cache.

Comment: Have you checked?

Comment: Looks great now it works.
Only need it be enable when I have it to yes insteed of no.

Comment: Greate, Please accept and upvote the answer, So it will help others in the community.

Comment: Have you updated the code so it will do it when the atrribute is enable and not disable?

Comment: I have updated my answer, So now if an attribute is enabled the Add to cart button will be hidden.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104842/discussion-between-kishor-thummar-and-kasper-elund).

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer, So it will help others in the community.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer.

Comment: Have another quesion for you.
If I want to add the text from a custom attribute in the order email how is the easiest way to do this?
The attribute name is placement_01
Want it to be under the sku of the product and only on the ones where this location is avaible.

Comment: Is it possible to add a second attribut with the name "obsolete" and that displays the text "no more in stock"

Answer (score 0):

Override the **product/view/addtocart.phtml** in your custom theme or module and then you can add condition

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->getAfhentes()): ?>   
        <div class="box-tocart">
            <div class="fieldset">
                <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
                <div class="field qty">
                    <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="number"
                            name="qty"
                            id="qty"
                            value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                            title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                            class="input-text qty"
                            data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <button type="submit"
                            title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                            class="action primary tocart"
                            id="product-addtocart-button">
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
                    </button>
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Pick up in store') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I replace my addtocart.phtml with this code correct?

Comment: my attribute yes/no name is: afhentes

Comment: Yes you need to also copy the product variable but now I have updated my answer so you can replace the addtocart.phtml in your theme or module